# initialize const char[] as non-static class member

Tags: c++, arrays, class

```
class foo {
  public:
    const char name[100];

    foo(const char name[]) : name(name) {};
};

int main(){
  foo("test");

  return 0;
}
```

Does not compile. How do I initialize `const char[]` non-static class member?

Comment: `memcpy` is your friend. `char name[100]` is a C anachronism, use `std::aray<char, 100>` in C++.

Comment: `std::string` looks to be a better fit. Arrays are really stupid. they were designed to solve the problems of the 1970 and they get the job done very well, but if you want the sort of magic you get from a more recently designed language like Java or Python, you need to use [C++ library containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: You're going to have to move that array into a separate class which has its own constructor taking a `char const*`, no other way around (short of an evil `const_cast`).

Answer (score 2):

You have different option, depending on what you want to achieve.

arrays in C++ are strange beasts, they do not behave like most other types, in particular they decay to pointers and do not have copy-constructors (unless wrapped in a structure/class).

`foo(const char name[])` does not take an array by value/by copy, it takes a pointer (yes, the syntax is confusing).

Thus `name(name)` is trying to initialize an array with a pointer.
If this would compile, it would make it super-easy to overflow the stack by accident, as there is no guarantee that the pointer name points to an array that is long at most 100 elements.

**Solution 1**

Use a more suitable construct - use a string.

From your snippet, it seems you want to store a piece of text (variable named `name`, initialisation with a string-literal...), so a std::string or other string-like class (even `const char*`) is a better construct.

```cpp
class foo {
  public:
    std::string name;

    explicit foo(std::string name_) : name(name_) {};
};
    
    int main(){
      foo("test");
    }
```

**Solution 2**

Use a better array

If you really need to store/copy an array, consider using `std::array` (since c++11)

```cpp
#include <array>

class foo {
   public:
     std::array<char, 100> name;

    explicit foo(std::array<char, 100> name_) : name(name_) {};
};

int main(){
    foo(std::array<char, 100>{"test"});
}
```

**Solution 3**

Pass the array by const-ref.

There are use--cases where you really want to use an array.
In this case you need to pass the value by reference, and copy the content with std::initializer_list (since c++14, but it's possible to emulate in c++11)

```cpp
#include <utility>
    
class foo {
  template <std::size_t... PACK1>
  explicit foo(const char (&name_)[100], std::index_sequence<PACK1...>)
    : name{ name_[PACK1]... }
  {}

  const char name[100];

  public:
  explicit foo(const char (&name_)[100])
    : foo(name_, std::make_index_sequence<100>{})
  {}
    
};
    
    int main(){
        const char hello[100] = "hello!";
        foo f = foo(hello);
    }
```

`const char (&arr)[100]` is an array of length 100 passed by const-reference.
As arrays do not have copy-constructors, we need to use `index_sequence` to initilize all members.

**Solution 4**

Use pointers and initialize the array in 2 phases.

Passing the array by const-reference means you need to create such a big array beforehand, and that you cannot pass a string literal which length is not exactly 101 (because of terminatig `\0`).

```cpp
#include <cstring>
    
class foo {
  const char name[100];
public:
  // constructor requires copy... unsure if needs to be so
  explicit foo(const char* name_)
  {
      std::copy(name_, name_ + std::strlen(name_), name);
  }
};
    
int main(){
    const char test[100] = "test!";
    foo f = foo(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would sugest to use a `std::string` if you are using c++, but if the `const char []` is a must, here is the solution, basically you just copy some portion of the shortest string to the array of size `100`, leaving unfilled the extra space(ie: `name` will result in `name = ['t','e','s','t','\0',...]`
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/91nC60

```
 #include <iostream>
    class foo{
        const char *name;
    public:
        void showme(){
            std::cout<<name<<std::endl;
        };
        foo(const char *_name) : name(_name) {
    
        };
    };
    
    int main(){
      foo a("test");
      a.showme();
      return 0;
    }
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
struct foo{
    const char *name;
    void showme(){
        std::cout<<name<<std::endl;
    };
};

int main(){
    foo a={
        .name="test"
    };
    a.showme();
    return 0;
}
```